# Dimension of the irreductible components of an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral ring which is a $k$ finitely generated algebra. Let $k \subset k'$ be a field extension. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $A \otimes_{k} k'$. I also suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal among the prime ideals of $A \otimes_{k} k'$. Why does $\dim(A \otimes_{k} k') = \dim(A \otimes_{k} k'/\mathfrak{p})$?

In other words, I want to show the irreducible components of $\operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes_{k} k')$ have all the same dimensions (in fact the dimension of $A \otimes_{k} k'$).

As $A \otimes_{k} k'$ is not necessarily integral, I couldn't link easly the height of $\mathfrak{p}$ (which I know is $0$) to the dimension of the ambient ring.

In fact, if $B$ is an arbitrary ring and
$V(\mathfrak{p})$ is an irreducible components of $Spec(B)$ (so that I can suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ prime and minimal among the prime ideals of $B$)  I have $V(\mathfrak{p}) \simeq \operatorname{Spec}(B/\mathfrak{p})$. Moreover, the inclusion $i : \operatorname{Spec}(B/\mathfrak{p}) \mapsto \operatorname{Spec}(B)$ is induce by the projection $B \mapsto B/\mathfrak{p}$ which is entire so by Cohen-Seidenberg $\dim(B) = \dim(B/\mathfrak{p})$ which concludes. Is this more general result true?

Comment: Sketch of argument: by Galois theory, “limit” arguments, discussions of irreducible components, and the fact that nilpotents or inseparability do not show up in the topology, we can assume that $k$ is algebraically closed. Then (by localization) we can assume that $A$ is smooth over $k$, of relative dimension $d$. Then $A \otimes k’$ is smooth of relative dimension $d$ over $k’$, in particular it is equidimensional of dimension $d$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Honestly, I don't see why we can assume k is algebraically closed. Could you be more precise please?  Moreover, do you have reference for the results you use about smoothness (smoothness of scheme I suppose : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_scheme ?) and the way it is linked with pure dimension?

Comment: For smoothness, I found *Néron Models*, by Bosch, Lütkebohmert and Raynaud, a good source. Here, it’s the *relative dimension* part that is important – otherwise I’m just using that a smooth scheme over a field has integral ring stalks (and therefore its connected components are irreducible).

Comment: We need $3$ steps to assume $k$ is algebraically closed: “descent” (if $X$ is a finite type $k$-scheme, $X_{k’}$ is pure for some extension $k’/k$, then $X$ is pure – take an affine open subset of $X$ contained in an irreducible component), “finite base change” (thanks to descent and the fact that inseparable field extensions are universal homeomorphisms, you can assume that your field extension is finite Galois, but the Galois group acts transitively on the irreducible components = primes above the zero of $A$), “limit” (geometric irreducible components are defined over a finite extension).

Comment: It might be possible to replace, with standard results (maybe somewhere in Qing Liu, *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, eg Prop 3.2.15 and Section 6.1?), the smoothness parts with another argument, where we use the generic rank of the sheaf of differential forms rather than relative dimension. It is also an invariant under field extension.

Comment: Your use of Cohen-Seidenberg is incorrect: the dimension equality for integral extensions of rings only works when the morphism is *injective*!

Comment: It's OK. I'll take a look to your references (even if some points still obscure to me; but I think it's due to a lack of commutative algebra knowledge). Thanks. And yes, I make a big mistake with Cohen-Seidenberg.

Comment: Actually, I’ve glanced at the duplicate and I think KReiser’s answer is interesting: the main point is that once, you’re on an algebraically closed field, irreducible components *remain* irreducible after any base change, so pureness is preserved.